# Clearing div element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

`onclick` on `<li>` element, I want to clear `div` which i will find by `id`. I have got a code

`javascript` this is how i writing code in a div:

```
document.getElementById("outputLaps").insertAdjacentHTML(
                "beforebegin",
                <br /> + "some code";
```

And that's how i try to clear the div:

```
document.getElementById("outputLaps").innerHTML = '';
```

or

```
var myNode = document.getElementById("outputLaps");
    while (myNode.firstChild) {
        myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
}
```

But they don't work.

@EDIT
Ok, i tried some solutions from answer but they are not working fine. I will try to explain it one more time.
I've got two elements. When i click on one, it adds some content to div. When i click on second element, i want to clear this div, not completely destroy it. Some solutions from the answers clear only something that i wrote in the div before first element add some code to it.

HTML

```
        <ul>            
            <li id="lap" onclick="displayLap()">Lap</li>
            <li id = "clear" onclick="clearLaps()">Clear laps</li>
        </ul>
<div id="outputLaps">rr</div>
```

First element on click add text:

```
function displayLap() {
    numberOfLap++;        
    document.getElementById("outputLaps").insertAdjacentHTML(
            "beforebegin",
            " Number of lap: " + numberOfLap + " time: " + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" + milliseconds
    );
```

}

Then i want to clear it with this function:

```
function clearLaps() {

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. But you want: Clearing div text via clicking on `<li>` tag, right?

Comment: Can you provide fiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @HappyCoding yes, when i click on li, i want the function onclick to clear the div, not only text, because as i wrote, i'm inserting <br /> + text

Comment: @HappyCoding I edited the question. Could you help me now?

Comment: I will give you a suggestion: Wrap the text (`" Number of lap: " + numberOfLap + ....`) to a `<div>` or a `<span>` tag with an id. If you want to clear it, call it by `document.getElementById('id_here').outterHTML = '';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally created what I wanted. Thanks everyone for answer. I had to change the way of adding text to the div, had to change it all on text so the innerHTML could clear it easy. I had to not use `<br />` but instead of "\n", so it display next text properly. Here what I have now:

html

```
      <ul>
            <li id="lap" onclick="displayLap()">Lap</li>
            <li id = "clear" onclick="clearLaps()">Clear laps</li>
       </ul>
<div id="outputLaps"></div>
```

JS

```
function displayLap() {
    numberOfLap++;
    var str = "Number of lap: " + numberOfLap + " time: " + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":0" + milliseconds + "\n";
    document.getElementById("outputLaps").appendChild(
            document.createTextNode(str))
}
function clearLaps() {
    numberOfLap = 0;
    document.getElementById("outputLaps").innerHTML = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close:

```
document.getElementById("outputLaps").outerHTML='';
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not working. There is an error in console: Cannot set property 'outerHTML' of null

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
var node = document.getElementById("outputLaps");
node.parentNode.replaceChild(node.cloneNode(false), node);
```

Or if you want to destroy all.

```
var node = document.getElementById("outputLaps");
node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
```

Comment: I don't want to destroy, only clear. Are you sure that it will work with insertAdjacentHTML? Because when i try your solve, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

for javascript use `.remove()`

```
document.getElementById("outputLaps").remove();
```

you can do this in jquery

```
$(function() {
   $("li").on("click",function() {
    $("#outputLaps").remove();
 });
});
```